# TabBarController and TableViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm very new to iOS development but I can do tables and many stuff I guess. I haven't built anything just yet.
So I'm building a tabBar based application, with 2 tabs. On both of them I'm having TableViews. Both are identical but with different data loaded. I have two viewControllers that extend UIViewController. These viewControllers classes are assigned to Views that have tables on them and segmented controls.[image]
This is a screenshot just in case :)
I'm thinking to create UITableViewController that will work for both tables.
What I'm thinking is to have a custom initializer inside TableViewController where I'll pass tableName and data from my UIViewController.

So a newbie questions: Is this a right way to do this? What would you guys recommend? Sorry if it's too silly but I couldn't find solution to this question.

Comment: So you want to use one class for both tableviewcontrollers???

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq I want to use one UITableViewController class for two different Table-s that are in two different views. And I don't know if it's the right way to approach it, what is the better practice

Comment: If the design is the same than you should use the same file.Keep in mind that the controller should not become complex or too lengthy otherwise you are good to handle it one class

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Alright, thank you mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No do not user one UITableViewController for two different views. First off it is bad practice and second you can't use a UITableViewController on a UIViewController. If you are thinking of adding a custom class to the tableView that is not how a UITableViewController works. Just makes sure to have two different custom classes for each view you are working with.